# Read/Write users properties

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to know if is possible read/write data from/to azure active directory ad by Javascript.
I read that there are REST services on Azure but the main issue is generate the token to talk with that and it seems that JS library doesn't exist for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such service. It is called [Windows Azure Active Directory Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx).

It is REST based and one can authenticate via OAuth to use it. Please note that currently the Resource Owner Password Flow is not supported in WAAD, but the regular token based authentication is. What you will need is:

- Get an overview of the [Graph API here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx).
- Create an application inside Azure AD so that you get an application credentials to use with the Graph API ([tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151122.aspx))
- Find some good JavaScript library that can generate OAuth headers (you can [start here](https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js)).

UPDATE

Actually you can't query the graph API from JavaScript as there is not CORS support for it. The only CORS supported services are Azure Mobile Services and Azure Storage. Which makes the use of a middle tier "service proxy" inevitable.
The only "JavaScript" stuff that will work with WAAD (Windows Azure AD) is the [developer preview of ADAL for Windows Store](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/04/22/windows-azure-authentication-library-aal-for-windows-store-a-deep-dive/).

As for where to keep OAuth key and secret everyone shall use their imagination. I never mentioned neither suggested to keep these on the client.

Comment: so basically the idea is have a middle layer between AD and my client application to get the credentials?

Comment: No. Just JavaScript and your AD.No Middle tier. You will of course understand this, when you go through the references I provided.

Comment: @astaykov Are you proposing to keep the secret key in client-side JavaScript code?

Comment: Ok the update helped me to better understand the solution and that confirm my idea about a middle tier

Comment: Note that if you are doing pure client-side JavaScript with no middle-tier (i.e. your own service as the middle tier), assuming you make it past any cross-site scription challenges, you should know that you will also have authentication challenges (at best, you might be able to authenticate and act as the user sitting in front of the computer, but you won't have full read/write privileges unless that user happens to be an admin in AAD).

Comment: (Because you should NOT EVER store the client secret key in client-side code.)

Comment: Philipe. How about acting as Application with the service principal? I also never mentioned Resource Owner Password Flow. All I mentioned were Application registration and application credentials! Not User credentials!